# convert string into rows with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00932

I have a string, like:

```
'one,two,three'
```

and I want to convert it in rows and use it into IN clause in an SQL:

```
one
two
three
```

I tried something like :

```
SELECT column_value 
  FROM XMLTable('"one","two","three"');
```

and it worked fine but in a join condition it fails.

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE 'one' IN (SELECT column_value 
                   FROM XMLTable('"one","two","three"'));
```

it gaves me the error:

> ```
> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CHAR
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
> ```

Can anyone help me on this, please?

**NOTE: I would like not use PLSQL**

Comment: Have you tried using this? `to_CHAT(columns)`

Comment: Using to_CHAT, will surely not work. Still not work using TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is nothing but just casting a **`CLOB`** value to a **`[VAR]CHAR[2]`** data type such as

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE 'one' IN (SELECT CAST(column_value AS VARCHAR2(20))
                   FROM XMLTable('"one","two","three"'))

1
---
  1
```

in order to make it comparable with a literal(such as `'one'`).

Moreover, **`CAST`** might be replaceable with **`XMLCast`** as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need XML to split the string and can use simple (fast) string functions:

```
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'one,two,three' FROM DUAL
),
bounds (value, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT value, 1, INSTR(value, ',', 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value, epos + 1, INSTR(value, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET order_id
SELECT CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos-spos)
       END as item
FROM   bounds;
```

Which outputs:

> | ITEM |
> | --- |
> | one |
> | two |
> | three |

---

### However

In your case you have an XY-problem and you **DO NOT NEED** to split the string as you can use `LIKE` to match the search string against a sub-string of your list:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM   dual
WHERE  ',' || :your_list || ',' LIKE '%,' || :search_value || ',%';
```

or with hardcoded strings:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM   dual
WHERE  ',' || 'one,two,three' || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'one' || ',%';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b1e8f4a7ebd04b1e655a8e5d9186d2ac)*

Answer (score 1):

Query that raised an error - if rewritten to this - works:

```
SQL> select 1
  2  from dual
  3  where 'one' in (select regexp_substr('one,two,three', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  4                  from dual
  5                  connect by level <= regexp_count('one,two,three', ',') + 1
  6                 );

         1
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Subquery (that uses `regexp_substr`) splits a comma-separated list of values (`'one,two,three'`) into rows.

---

Alternatively, if you use Oracle Apex (or have it installed in your database), you can simplify it by utilizing `apex_string.split`:

```
SQL> select 1
  2  from dual
  3  where 'one' in (select * from apex_string.split('one,two,three', ','));

         1
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `REGEXP_COUNT` to find your word in the list.

This would be faster than converting

But read this canonical thread [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

> ```
> SELECT
>     CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT('one,two,three', '^([^,]+,)*one(,[^,]+)*$', 1, 'i') > 0
>         THEN 1 ELSE 0
>     END as cnt
> FROM DUAL;
> ```
>
> ```
> | CNT |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e3480fe8ca7da185249580c58276dddf)*